# Extend LVM when all 4 primary partitions have been taken

Tags: lvm

I've been asked to increase the disk size of an LVM managed CentOS (virtual) server. The current partition table is as follows:

```
Disk /dev/vda: 429.5 GB, 429496729600 bytes, 838860800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ba858

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/vda1 * 2048 1026047 512000 83 Linux
/dev/vda2 1026048 104857599 51915776 8e Linux LVM
/dev/vda3 104857600 314572799 104857600 8e Linux LVM
/dev/vda4 314572800 629145599 157286400 8e Linux LVM
```

There's a total of 4 primary partitions and there's about 100GB of free space. Since the maximum allowed primary partitions is limited to 4 a new one can't be added.

When using ext4 partitions I think I could just use fdisk, delete /dev/vda4 and re-add it with the same starting position but a new end position. However, LVM isn't my forte. Will I be able to do the same thing with LVM? I assume one would also need to call the `lvextend` command as well as a `resize2fs`/`xfs_growfs` afterwards?

Output of lvdisplay:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_directadmin/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                vg_directadmin
  LV UUID                qD1ib9-TAqx-gkKb-9ybC-Jg7g-653o-dDehoj
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2015-07-08 15:02:22 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                1.00 GiB
  Current LE             256
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_directadmin/lv_tmp
  LV Name                lv_tmp
  VG Name                vg_directadmin
  LV UUID                ezqLis-CBQt-IiZK-7BjX-gvf5-b476-xxlkTe
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2015-07-08 15:02:22 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.00 GiB
  Current LE             256
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_directadmin/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                vg_directadmin
  LV UUID                FfvRs5-bQav-72te-GxcF-wlan-hWoT-Ir3I36
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2015-07-08 15:02:23 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                297.50 GiB
  Current LE             76160
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took the afternoon to study up on LVM and found a solution. So, my initial solution turns out to be a working solution. Here's what I did.

1. Use `fdisk` to make `/dev/vda4` bigger. To do that delete partition 4, re-add it as a primary partition and let it make use of all available sectors. It'll ask you about deleting the LVM2_member signature, make sure to answer **no**. Set partition type to Linux LVM (8e). Write the new partition table.
2. `pvresize /dev/vda4`.
3. `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg_directadmin/lv_root`.
4. Finally you need to resize `/dev/vg_directadmin/lv_root` with resize2fs (or xfs_growfs on CentOS 7 if I'm not mistaken). I had to do a disk check as well with `e2fsck -f /dev/vg_directadmin/lv_root` followed by `resize2fs /dev/vg_directadmin/lv_root`.
5. Finally, remount.

Hope this helps someone else. [Linux LVM on HowToForge is a helpful tutorial as well!](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm)

Comment: You can do all operations online, when the volume is mounted. I wrote a small script for this: https://github.com/mircea-vutcovici/scripts/blob/master/vol_resize.sh The script will just show the commands you need to run. If you find any bug I am happy to fix them.

Comment: Thanks, will be interesting to take a look at your script.

Comment: Good. Perfect. Thank you!